# Why does my producer blocks forever sometimes?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am trying to implement a producer/consumer class in `C#` using `Monitor`.
Ideas is that the consumer must block until producer has some item for consumer but producer should keep on producing.
My producer produces some item and then just waits/sleeps for sometime before producing again.

The problem I saw that the producer never wakes up from `Thread.Sleep(time)`.
Maybe there is a deadlock situation somewhere.

Please help me understand this.

Just as a note, I don't want to use `BlockingCollection` ... 
Here is my code...

```
public class ProducerConsumerEx
    {
        private object _objLocker = new object();
        private Thread _tProducer;
        private Queue<string> _producerQueue;
        private bool _keepProducing;
        public ProducerConsumerEx()
        {
            _keepProducing = false;
            _producerQueue = new Queue<string>();
            _tProducer = new Thread(Produce);
            _tProducer.IsBackground = true;
        }

        private void Produce()
        {
            while (_keepProducing)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"PRODUCER {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId} LOOP");
                lock (_objLocker)
                {
                    string item = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
                    _producerQueue.Enqueue(item);
                    Console.WriteLine($"PRODUCER {DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss")} Thread {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId} Inserted {item}");
                    Monitor.Pulse(_objLocker);
                    Console.WriteLine($"PRODUCER {DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss")} Thread {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId} AF Pulse {item}");
                }
                Console.WriteLine($"PRODUCER {DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss")} Thread {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId} BF Sleep");
                Thread.Sleep(10000);
                Console.WriteLine($"PRODUCER {DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss")} Thread {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId} AF Sleep");
            }
        }
        public void Start()
        {
            if (!_keepProducing)
            {
                _tProducer.Start();
                _keepProducing = true;
            }
        }
        public string Consume()
        {
            string val = default(string);
            Console.WriteLine($"CONSUMER {DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss")} Thread {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId} BF Consume");

            lock (_objLocker)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"CONSUMER {DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss")} Thread {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId} BF Consume Inside");
                if (_producerQueue.Count > 0)
                {
                    val = _producerQueue.Dequeue();
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"CONSUMER {DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss")} Thread {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId} WAITING");
                    Monitor.Wait(_objLocker);
                    //
                    if (_producerQueue.Count > 0)
                    {
                        val = _producerQueue.Dequeue();
                    }
                }
            }
            return val;
        }
    }
```

And the use of this class is like this

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {           
            ProducerConsumerEx pc = new ProducerConsumerEx();
            pc.Start();
            while (true)
            {
                string t = pc.Consume();
                Console.WriteLine($"Main {t}");
            }       
        }
```

Comment: You should switch the lines `_tProducer.Start();` and             `_keepProducing = true;`, you never know if the thread is started before the `_keepProducing = true;` or after.

Comment: Are you sure the `Console.WriteLine` after `Thread.Sleep` is not executed?

Comment: @slawekwin Yes, I am sure, Console.WriteLine is not executed that's what I don't understand ...

Comment: [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JamZth) seems to be working

Answer (score 1):

To implement a consumer/producer pattern, I recommand using `BlockingCollection`:

A little example :

```
    private BlockingCollection<string> _producerQueue;

    void Consume()
    {
        foreach (var item in _producerQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
        {
           //do some work there
        }
    }

    void Produce()
    {
       _producerQueue.Add("a string to consume");
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(Consume);
    }
```

From MSDN :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312(v=vs.110).aspx

> Provides blocking and bounding capabilities for thread-safe
>   collections that implement IProducerConsumerCollection.

You can find some examples there :

http://dotnetpattern.com/csharp-blockingcollection

Answer (score -1):

You `Monitor.Wait(_objLocker);` is within the `lock (_objLocker)` statement. This way the producer never can add and signal the consumer. You should bring the `Monitor.Wait(_objLocker);` outside the `lock (_objLocker)`

Something like:  *(pseudo)*

```
public string Consume()
{
    string val = default(string);
    Console.WriteLine($"CONSUMER {DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss")} Thread {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId} BF Consume");

    int count = 0;

    lock (_objLocker)
        count = _producerQueue.Count;

    if (count == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"CONSUMER {DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss")} Thread {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId} WAITING");
        Monitor.Wait(_objLocker);
    }

    lock (_objLocker)
        val = _producerQueue.Dequeue();

    return val;
}
```

Comment: This is what I thought too, but it's not how [Monitor.Wait/Pulse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ateab679(v=vs.110).aspx) works

Comment: Never used Monitor. I always use resetevents. I might assume wrong that monitor wait/pulse works the same.